# What is the return type of Specification after creating a join with criteria API

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I don't understand how to return the query after making the join and adding the predicate in the specification in this code. Can Anyone help me?

```
public class QueriesEntity {    
    @Column(name = "query_id")
    @Id
    private int queryId;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String description;
    
    private String query;
    
    private Integer owner;
    
    @Column(name = "conn_id")
    private Integer dataSourceId;
    
    @Column(name = "created_dt")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDt;
    
    @Column(name = "updated_dt")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDt; 
    
    @Column(name = "container_id")
    private Integer containerId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "conn_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private DataSourceEntity dataSourceEntity;
```

public static Specification filters(Integer containerId, Integer queryID, Integer datasourceId) {

```
    return new Specification<QueriesEntity>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<QueriesEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            
             query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(QueriesEntity.class);
             root = query.from(QueriesEntity.class);
            Join<QueriesEntity, DataSourceEntity> join = root.join("dataSourceEntity", JoinType.INNER);
            
            List<Predicate> outerPreds = new ArrayList<>();
            if (containerId != null) {
                Predicate containerIdPred = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("containerId"), containerId);
                outerPreds.add(containerIdPred);
            }
            if(queryID > 0) {
                Predicate queryIdPred = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("queryId"), queryID);
                outerPreds.add(queryIdPred);
            }
            if(datasourceId != null) {
                Predicate datasourceIdPred = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("dataSourceId"), datasourceId);
                outerPreds.add(datasourceIdPred);
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.and(outerPreds.toArray(new Predicate[outerPreds.size()]));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the Join option you shouldn't use the root to get fields, use the Join instead:

```
if (containerId != null) {
    Predicate containerIdPred = criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("containerId"), containerId);
    outerPreds.add(containerIdPred);
}
```

Example code:

```
public static Specification<QueriesEntity> filters(Integer containerId, Integer queryID, Integer datasourceId) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<QueriesEntity, DataSourceEntity> join = root.join("dataSourceEntity", JoinType.INNER);
        List<Predicate> outerPreds = new ArrayList<>();
        if (containerId != null) {
            Predicate containerIdPred = cb.equal(join.get("containerId"), containerId);
            outerPreds.add(containerIdPred);
        }
        if(queryID > 0) {
            Predicate queryIdPred = cb.equal(join.get("queryId"), queryID);
            outerPreds.add(queryIdPred);
        }
        if(datasourceId != null) {
            Predicate datasourceIdPred = cb.equal(root.get("dataSourceId"), datasourceId);
            outerPreds.add(datasourceIdPred);
        }
        return cb.and(outerPreds.stream().toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    };
}
```

Comment: Also How to add the DataSourceEntity fields in the Select Clause??

Comment: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [containerId] on this ManagedType [com.datagaps.coreservicerest.entity.DataSourceEntity];

Comment: The Join should be in reverse order Join<DataSourceEntity, QueriesEntity>
You can access the atributes of both entities from the joinCapOption

Comment: Even After making this => Join<DataSourceEntity, QueriesEntity> Getting the Same Error.

Comment: You are overriding the root and query of the specification. Try removing that lines before the join.

Comment: Can u give a sample modified Code?? From Above

Comment: I have edited the answer to post an example code. It uses Java 8 Lambda features, but the structure is the same: create the join and the list, add contidions to the list, concat the list with an and

Comment: Still same issue Even After Using your Code

Comment: Can u edit your post and share the entities to see if there is a problem there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241813/discussion-between-vinay-saddanapu-and-arkaitz).

Comment: public class DataSourceEntity {
 @Id
    @Column(name = "data_src_id")
     private Integer dataSrcId;
     
     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;
}